# What do resonant frequencies of the Helmholtz equation correspond to in the wave equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, resonance, vibrations

Time-harmonic electromagnetic and acoustic waves are governed by the Helmholtz equation

$$\Delta u + k^2 u = 0,$$

in the frequency domain. This is an eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian and the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions correspond to resonant frequencies. What do these resonant frequencies correspond to in the time domain version of the problem, that is, the wave equation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the Helmholtz equation represents an eigenvalue problem, then there would also be boundary conditions involved. For instance, if we want to use the Helmholtz equations to find the modes in an optical fibre. The boundary conditions would be the continuity conditions at the interfaces between different media, together with requirements that the field remains finite and goes to zero at infinity. In such a case the eigenvalues would represent the propagation contants of the different modes, which are the eigenfunctions. So eigenvalues are not always associated with resonant frequencies.

The physical meaning of the Helmholtz equation remains the same regardless of whether one considers it in the time domain or in the frequency domain. The reason for choosing to consider either the frequency or time domain version usually has to do with convenience in terms of how to solve the equation for the given boundary conditions.

In the case of a resonant cavity (boundary conditions typically restrict the field to a finite volume) where the eigenvalues do represent resonant frequencies, the eigenfunctions represent all the modes that can exist in that cavity. These eigenfunctions will be functions of the spatial coordinate, multiplied by a harmonic function in time $\exp(i\omega_n t)$, where $\omega_n$ are the resonant frequency (eigenvalue).